# c++ passing array through function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

my question is simple. I'm trying to pass an array of int's through a function.
But something went wrong on the other side. I don't get data out of it.

Create some 2 data arrays and send them to the mesh class.

```
GLfloat vertices[] =    {   0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
                            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                            -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f  };

GLuint indices[] =      {   0, 1, 3,
                            1, 2, 3 };

Mesh mesh;
mesh.SetVertices(vertices);
mesh.SetIndices(indices);
```

Here is my header:

```
void SetVertices(GLfloat* vertices);
void SetIndices(GLuint* indices);
```

And my cpp:

```
void Mesh::SetVertices(GLfloat* vertices) {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); }

void Mesh::SetIndices(GLuint* indices) {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); }
```

I've also tested it storing the arrays directly in the SetVertices/SetIndices methods and that worked just fine.

Cheers M.

Comment: You need to pass the size as another parameter. `sizeof(vertices)` yields the size of the pointer variable only.

Comment: Thank u, that works!